# why is $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)$ always approximately $1$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing an exercise from a computer programming book and was asked to determine the following:

> why is $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)$ always approximately $1$ for any theta?

Can someone please explain why the result is always approximately $1$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax or LaTeX as I did to format your question. Thanks. 

Btw, $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$

Comment: It should be **exactly** $1$, but you have numerical errors

Comment: In fact $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$ with exact equality for any number $\theta$.

Comment: how can I validate the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in math, it is exactly $1$. I have no experience in programming but presumably, when you write a program to approximate $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$, it will always give something close to the exact value. Here's a short proof. Let $\theta$ be an angle in a right angled triangle, and let the lengths of the adjacent side to that angle, the opposite side, and the hypotenuse be $\mathrm{adj.}$, $\mathrm{opp.}$ and $\mathrm{hyp.}$ respectively.

$$\begin{split}\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta & = \left(\frac{\mathrm{adj.}}{\mathrm{hyp}}\right)^2 +  \left(\frac{\mathrm{opp.}}{\mathrm{hyp}}\right)^2\\
& = \frac{\mathrm{adj.}^2+\mathrm{opp.}^2}{\mathrm{hyp.}^2}\\
& =^* \frac{\mathrm{hyp.}^2}{\mathrm{hyp.}^2}\\
& = 1.
\end{split}$$

Note that the starred equality $=^*$ follows because of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Most computer implementations of $\sin$ and $\cos$ rely on their Taylor series approximation. If you consider the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, square them, and add them, you'll see that all the coefficients of $x^1$ to $x^{2n-1}$ vanish, so the Taylor series of $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$ turns out to be $1 + c_{2n}x^{2n}$, and for large enough values of $n$, this is close to $1$. That's why your calculator/computer will often tell you $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$ is approximately $1$. In fact, it turns out that it's exactly $1$, as the other answers point out.

Answer (score 2):

$\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)$ is always equal to $1$ in the mathematical world. This is the Pythagorean Theorem.

In the computer world, this is not so because computer arithmetic has limited precision. Moreover, even when $\theta$ is given in degrees as a fraction, $\sin^2(\theta)$ is never a fraction, except in three cases. This is [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem).

On the other hand, this does not mean that $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)$ is *never* exactly $1$ in a computer. Actually, it *is* exactly $1$ for many values of $\theta$. Indeed, this [program](https://ideone.com/n6JIGB) shows that it is exactly $1$ for over 75% of 32000+ rational numbers uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,6.25]$.

The reason is probably that  $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)=1$ is used in the computation of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. Moreover, and more importantly, these values are computed to be correct up to one [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), at least for $\theta$ not very large. If you print the errors $v-1.0$ in that program, you'll see this.

Comment: It’s also important to note that not all finite representation in base 10 are finite in base 2 for floating point arithmetic. So even if there are rational numbers like 0.1 in base 10, this has an infinite binary representation that’s subject to floating point error.

Answer (score 1):

Near 0 we have approximations:

$$ \cos(\theta) = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2} + O(\theta^3),\quad \sin(\theta) = \theta + O(\theta^3)$$

Thus, near 0,

$$ \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)  \approx (1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2})^2 + \theta^2 = 1. $$
This is correct up to $O(\theta^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit circle is a right triangle with radius $1$. By definition $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the segment forming the hypotenuse of the triangle.

Let's define $s_1$ as the side opposite to $\theta$. Recall that the hypotenuse of the triangle is $1$. Therefore, $$\sin \theta=\frac{s_1}{1}=s_1$$
Then, let's define the leg of the triangle adjacent to $\theta$ as $s_2$. Again using SOHCAHTOA, $$s_2=\cos\theta$$
Then, using the Pythagorean Theorem, $$s_1^2+s_2^2=1^2=1$$
Therefore, $$\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta=1$$
This is rightfully called the Pythagorean Identity.